# Webflux Mono Chaining - Multiple dependent service calls with exception handling not working in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive-programming, reactive, spring-webclient

I am new to Webclient and reactive programming , have to invoke multiple service which are dependent on, I am not able to handle the exception in each stage. Any help appreciated

1. ServiceOne to get the token - I am able to handle exception
2. Use above service Token and call the loginService -** Not able to handler error Scenario**
3. Call the other service using response from Service 2.

below is my code

```
    User user = new User();
    Mono<Token> token = tokenGen.generateToken();  - Service 1
    // Working fine
    token.doOnError(ex-> {
    log.info("Token Error  : " + ex.getMessage());
    try {
        logErrorService.uploadLog(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    }).flatMap(token -> {
       String accessToken = token.accessToken();
       Mono<Res> loginResponse = loginService.publish(user, accessToken); - Service 2 
       // Not able to handle exception 
       return loginResponse;
    }).map(loginService ->{
    String userName = loginService.getName();
        send to other service.   - Service 3
    
    }).subscribe();


   --- each webclient call , I have added onStatus to handle exception
   
   
   public Mono<Token> generateToken() {
 
    headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE);
    Mono<Token> token = webClient
        .post()
        .uri(uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString())
        .headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
        .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(formData))
        .retrieve()
        .onStatus(httpStatus -> !httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful(),
            clientResponse -> handleServiceErrorResponse(clientResponse.statusCode()))
        .bodyToMono(Token.class);
    return token;
  }
   
     private Mono<? extends Throwable> handleServiceErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode statusCode) {
      return Mono.error(new ServiceException(statusCode.value());
  }
```

I tried to handle exception , able to handle in first service , if I add same code into other service it is not called.

Below code is not working.

```
.flatMap(token -> {
       String accessToken = token.accessToken();
       Mono<Res> loginResponse = loginService.publish(user, accessToken); - Service 2 
       // Not able to handle exception 
    doOnError(ex-> {
    log.inof("ERROR in LogIn service: " + ex.getMessage());
    try {
        logErrorService.uploadLog(ex.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
 
       return loginResponse;
    })
```